Error: Cannot resolve type entity i10.MatLegacyDialogModule to symbol while compiling Angular 18 application
I have updated my NX Angular monorepo to version 18.2.7 from 15.2.0. When I am trying to build my app, it is throwing the below error
./apps/apc/ui/src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js): Error: Cannot resolve type entity i10.MatLegacyDialogModule to symbol.
I tried so many different ways but couldn't solve the issue. Any help would be appreciated!

With Angular 17, the Angular Material legacy components were removed. This is the reason why you are seeing the error. You need to downgrade Angular Material v16 which still include the legacy components. The other Angular packages can be updated to Angular 18. This approach will not be supported anymore with Angular v19, so in the long run you need to do the MDC migration.

Hi @JSON Derulo thank you for the reply. I am not using any legacy material modules in my code and I migrated to Angular 18 not 17. Anyways, I will try with your solution and let you know how it goes!
